# Share web page/dynamic infographic as image

Tags: facebook, image, wordpress, dynamic, pinterest

I've created a dynamically updating infographic (made dynamic with PHP, CSS and jQuery), and I'd like to be able to export it/share it as an image, so it could be pinned on pinterest, shared on facebook (and not just appear as a web page), etc...

Any ideas? I'm not really sure where to start.

It's in Wordpress, if that makes a difference.